# Discord.js Sharding, How do you send an embed message with broadcastEval?

Tags: discord.js, sharding

I'm trying to send an embed message to an specific channel **with a sharded bot**.
I've achieved sending a simple message successfully with this code:

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
      (async () => {
             let channel = await this.channels.get("683353482748756047"); 
             channel.send("Hello")
      })()
`)
```

The problem starts when I want to send an embed message. I've tried passing the variable like this:

```js
//exampleEmbed is created
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
      (async () => {
             let channel = await this.channels.get("683353482748756047"); 
             channel.send('${exampleEmbed}')
      })()
`)
```

but the message is sent like "[object Object]".

I thought about returning the channel object back outside of broadcastEval and then sending my variable, but I've read this is not possible because you can't return full discord objects.

How should I send the embed message? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by creating the embed message inside the broadcastEval, and using the '${}' syntax to poblate it.

Example:

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
      (async () => {
             const Discord = require('discord.js');
             let channel = await this.channels.get("683353482748756047"); 
             if(channel){
                  //if shard has this server, then continue.
                  let message = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                  .setThumbnail(this.user.displayAvatarURL)
                  .setTitle('Title')
                  .addField("Something useful:", '${useful}')
                  .addField("Another useful thing:", '${useful2}')
                  .setTimestamp()
                    
                  channel.send(message)
             }
       })()
```

Comment: ahm could you send the working code now because i am also struggling with the same problem, but i cannot really follow you solution text

Comment: You can also do:
```
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
      (async () => {
             const Discord = require('discord.js');
             let channel = await this.channels.get("683353482748756047"); 
             if(channel){
                  channel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed(data))
             }
       })()
```
In my example, this was helpful because it was helpful to form the rich embed in parent functions and pass the message as a parameter.